# Expanding macro inside raw string

Tags: c++, string, c++11, macros

I would like to do some debugging of my crazy macros, but there's no way to do it because macros generate code, not strings. I'd have to change the macros to emit strings in order for my program to print out the code that it would otherwise produce.

New in C++11 are [`R"delim("Raw Strings")delim"`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal), and I was hoping that there is some way to interpolate code-macros inside of one of these to turn that code into a string literal.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Can you give an example of what you'd like to do? Like, "Here's a macro, and here's what I want to do with it."

Comment: Can't you just use [macro stringification](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html)?

Comment: You guys are underestimating how crazy the macros are

Comment: @StevenLu - if you can't debug the macros without heroic efforts, then you need to be eliminating them. Write-once code is bad!

Comment: Well, it's for über-highlevel (truly write-once) debug instrumentation that adds general-purpose reflection capabilities to the language. It's functionality that is *literally* impossible to implement without using macros (which are 3 levels deep and generate templates).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to debug your crazy macros, you'd probably get more mileage out of directly examining the preprocessed output. Any C/C++ compiler will have an option for this. In GCC it's `-E`; for MSVC, I don't recall where it is exactly, but one of the properties sections has "keep preprocessed output". When you do this, keep your #includes to a minimum, especially standard-library #includes; these can add hundreds or thousands of lines of code to the top of the preprocessed output.

Comment: FYI: For VC it's `/P`

Answer (score 2):

Raw string literals concatenate the same way as normal string literals.

```
#define MYMACRO "hello"
std::string blah = R"(first part -)" MYMACRO R"(- second part)";
std::cout << blah;
```

will output `first part -hello- second part`